I want to build an iOS application using Codemagic, but an error message appears
I want to build an iOS application using Codemagic, but an error message appears :
Did not find matching provisioning profiles for code signing!

No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trust

For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/
  AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing

I hope you can help me solve this problem

welcome to StackOverflow, however try to update your question to include maximum details what is not clear in the error message, what have you tried and what exact problem/blocker you have faced. Also try to search for existing questions before asking. I hope it makes sense

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To build ios application and distribute it you need 2 certificate(1 for signing and 1 for distribution)and 1 provisioning profile(app store distribution profile). You can create them on apple website and let codemagic fetch it but to do that you need to connect apple developer portal to codemagic in teams integration. And in the yml use these certificate and profile.
Do this: First check this video
This will tell you how to add apple key to codemagic.
After that  generate the above 2 certificate and 1 provisioning profile. After that use there reference in codemagic.yml.For this check out this doc and this video
